# Twitter client for Windows that will show all available tweets

Tags: windows, twitter

Is there a Windows client for Twitter that let you scroll your timeline showing all available tweets (last 3200)?

Comment: what do you mean by "scroll you timeline"? make  a single api request? that can be done in 10 seconds. is that all?

Comment: If you're using Windows 8.1/10,  there's an official Twitter Metro app. I don't remember for sure,  but I think it comes preinstalled? If not,  just search the Store for Windows.

Comment: @AlanCoromano Api is rate limited, and didnt find a client that shows more than 800

Comment: @Jogai, how exactly limited? that's only 1 request, probably per day.

Comment: @AlanCoromano I looked into the api (before posting the question). The call is this: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/home_timeline with a rate limit of 15 (per 15 minute window) and a maximum of 200 returned tweets. The limit is actually 800, the 3200 is for getting a user_timeline instead of the home_timeline.

Comment: @Jogai, so you want to get 3200 tweets for the home_timeline?

Comment: @AlanCoromano Yes

Comment: Today I just got time to play with it a bit . 
So why can't you just request 800 tweets 4 times? It'll take you 45 minutes. 
Is 15 mins mean that you can only request at most 800 tweets on you home timeline for the last 15 minutes? 
Or does it mean that there must be a 15 mins gap between 15 api calls? 
What does "15 mins" exactly mean?

Comment: I'm afraid "Up to 800 Tweets are obtainable on the home timeline" means at maximum. I should build something to test this out I'm afraid.